# Loop to assign new values to multiple spatial dataframes

Tags: r, loops, spatial, assign, spatial-data-frame

I am working in RStudio (V 0.99.467) running R (V3.2.2) on Windows10. I have a collection of vector maps from ArcGIS that I read into R with a loop using rgdal to create objects of class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame'.

There are several data QAQC checks and fixes that I would like to perform in the same loop. For example, I wish to remove spaces from entries in the data frame. I can do this easily outside the loop, but struggle with the referencing and name assignments within the loop. Outside of a loop, this command removes all the spaces in the data:

```
# the function I want to apply to each map immediately after I read it
as.data.frame(apply(get(mymap)@data[],2,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x)))
```

This function also works within the loop, but I can't reassign the new no-spaces data to replace the original data. Here is some example code to show what I am trying to do and where I get stuck.

```
# vector of names from map objects
farmnames <- c("Gardner","Mistletoe","Omni","Sturgill")  
library(rgdal)  
# create vector of filenames based on farmnames
filenames <- paste0(farmnames[],"_Farm_Fields_FINAL")  
# loop to read maps and correct data
for (i in 1:length(farmnames)){  
    name <- farmnames[i]  
    assign(name, readOGR(".", filenames[i])) # create map object  
    get(name)@data[]<- as.data.frame(apply(get(name)@data[],2,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x))) # remove spaces from map dataframe
}
```

But this last line returns the error: "Error in get(name)@data[] <- as.data.frame(apply(get(name)@data[], 2,: could not find function "get<-". I'm guessing that I can't put a function on the left side of an assignment? Because if I just type "get(name)@data[]" R returns the correct answer without errors.

I've also tried various methods creating a temporary dataframe, changing the temporary dataframe, and then using the assign function to replace the dataframe within the map object.  But again, this works outside the loop (assign(mymap@data[],d)) and not within the loop (assign(get(name)@data[],d)).

```
# method 2
d <- as.data.frame(apply(d,2,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x)))  
assign(get(name)@data[],d)
```

But this method returns the error: "Error in assign(get(name)@data[], d) : invalid first argument". Presumably because the first argument in assign is supposed to be a single element (variable name), not a dataframe?

I've also created a subloop to iterate through the variable names making corrections column by column - but this seems very inefficient when I could perform all corrections with a single line in the main loop - if I could just get the assignments to work. I'm hoping someone has a solution for using either of the two examples I pasted above.

I am not sure how to attach example raw data for an object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame within StackOverflow.  If there is not enough information here to help me, I can perhaps create a public folder on GitHub and provide a link?  But I expect this is a pretty basic assignment problem as I am still very new to R and programming.

Comment: Can't you do it this way: `for (name in farmnames){ 
  temp      <- readOGR(".",paste0(name,"_Farm_Fields_FINAL") ) ;
  temp@data <- as.data.frame(lapply(temp@data,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x)));
  assign(name,temp)
}`

Comment: Yes!  That works.  I had tried some solutions with (name in farmnames) when I learned yesterday that I could index like this - but never got it working.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Added this as an answer to close out the question.

Answer (score 1):

So this should (apparently does) work.

```
farmnames <- c("Gardner","Mistletoe","Omni","Sturgill")  
for (name in farmnames){ 
  temp <- readOGR(".",paste0(name,"_Farm_Fields_FINAL") )
  temp@data <- as.data.frame(lapply(temp@data,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x)))
  assign(name,temp) 
  # rm(temp)
}
```

Note that this creates a variable `temp` at each iteration of the loop and creates a *new* variable with the appropriate name at the end. If space is an issue, un-comment the last line, which deletes the `temp` variable at each step.

Demonstration:

```
for (name in farmnames){ 
  temp <- as.data.frame(matrix(paste(LETTERS[1:25],sample(1:25,25)),nc=5))
  temp <- as.data.frame(lapply(temp,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x)))
  assign(name,temp) 
  rm(temp)
}
ls()
# [1] "farmnames" "Gardner"   "Mistletoe" "name"      "Omni"      "Sturgill"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by jhoward may work, but using 'assign' (and get) is generally not a good approach. It is much clearer and easier to use a list. Although, as you do not specify what you want to do with these objects after the loop, it is hard to be sure. I would do:

```
farmnames <- c("Gardner", "Mistletoe", "Omni", "Sturgill")  
x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(farmnames)){ 
  temp <- readOGR(".", paste0(farmname[i], "_Farm_Fields_FINAL") )
  temp@data <- as.data.frame(lapply(temp@data,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x)))
  x[i] <- temp
}
```

Or perhaps using the trim function from the raster package to get cleaner code (I am assuming that what you call "vector maps" are in fact shapefiles):

```
library(raster)
farmnames <- c("Gardner", "Mistletoe", "Omni", "Sturgill")  
x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(farmnames)){ 
    filename <- paste0(farmname[i], "_Farm_Fields_FINAL.shp")
    temp <- shapefile(filename)
    temp@data <- trim(temp@data)
    x[i] <- temp
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions!  All work with the difference of producing many individual objects (with get/assign) vs a single list (with apply and list).  This is just the first step in a function to read, clean, and output data from shapefiles where people have entered the data with little attention to detail (e.g. inconsistent formatting and ordering of columns).  It will be used within reactive code in a Shiny UI.  Next steps include appending data to the map object dataframes. I'll use a list solution, because that's ultimately what I need from the larger function in which the loop occurs.